# Adding a getter to Array.prototype

Tags: javascript

I wanted to add a getter to Array.prototype to get the last element of the array.

I did it like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'last', {
    get: function() {
        return this[this.length - 1];
    }
});
```

Is this proper for memory? My worry was if you instance 10000 objects:

- I hope I will only have 1 functions in the memory
- My worry is that I might have 10000 * 1 = 10000 functions in the memory

My goal is to use it like this:

```
const arr = [{}, {}, {}, {}];
arr.last === arr[arr.length - 1];
```

Comment: Your solution is fine, you define new property ״last״ to the Array.prototype object, so it will be for all the arrays object that you will create after it. Same one method instance for all arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works the way you want it to, the prototype of each instance refers to the same object.

> In JavaScript, they are not copied over — instead, a link is made between the object instance and its prototype (its **proto** property, which is derived from the prototype property on the constructor), and the properties and methods are found by walking up the chain of prototypes.
>
> Read more about working with prototype:
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)

You can easily test this:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'last', {
    get: function() {
        return this[this.length - 1];
    }
});

const arr = [1,2,3,4];
const arr2 = [5,6,7,8];

console.log(arr.__lookupGetter__("last") === arr2.__lookupGetter__("last")); // => true iff there is only one last()-function
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

```js
Array.prototype.last = function() {
       return this[this.length - 1];
    };
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
console.log(arr.last());
```

You can extend `Array` to get this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with modifying prototypes of base-classes is that if you do it, other people could do it too and then combining code from multiple authors the versions might silently conflict. Somebody else's version of the method last() might override yours without you realizing it, and might return a different result than you expect, without you realizing it.

A better way in my opinion is to provide a simple way to create a wrapper -object around arrays on demand, the wrapper-object then has methods like last() which returns the last element of the now wrapped array inside it. It could look this:

```
w ([1, 2, 3]).last()
```

More on the wrapper-approach especially as applied to the last() -method for Arrays see:  https://medium.com/@panuviljamaa/why-javascript-needs-the-method-last-9f4e285f3f7d